# Как изменить направление вектора в UE?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4, unreal-engine

Вопрос к тем, кто работает в UE.
Я хочу заставить двигаться обычный куб по диагонали и у меня даже получилось это сделать. Так вот, скажите, пожалуйста, каким образом я могу менять угол наклона под которым будет двигаться куб, то есть изменить угол вектора скорости?
Данный метод вызываю каждый кадр.

```
void ABeaverLog::LogMovement(float DeltaTime)
{
    xAngle = GetActorLocation();
    const FVector newLocation = FVector{xAngle.X - speed * DeltaTime, xAngle.Y, xAngle.Z - speed * DeltaTime};
    SetActorLocation(newLocation);
}
```